# 2 versões diferentes do PHP(cli) no Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: php, ubuntu

Instalei o PHP 5.6 no Ubuntu 14.04LTS utilizando os seguintes comandos:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Porém ao executar o comando `php -v` obtenho a seguinte resposta:

```
PHP 5.3.29 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2016 18:12:10) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Porém, se executar o comando `php5 -v` obtenho a seguinte resposta:

```
PHP 5.6.18-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

O que eu fiz de errado?

Comment: @DanielOmine eu li sim! Eu já montei o servidor várias vezes! Só que dessa vez fiz algo errado que não consigo entender o que é. O link que você postou não ajudou a resolver o problema (embora valeu a pena porque aprendi alguns coisas), lá o autor quer fazer um downgrade da versão do PHP. O único repositório que tenho é o que postei na pergunta (versão 5.6) e mesmo assim aparece 5.3.29. Não sei o que poderá ser.

Comment: Eu sempre uso esse tutorial aqui https://www.digitaloceanbr.com.br/configurar-servidor-lemp-linux-nginx-mysql-php.html eu recomendo. simples e eficiente

Comment: @DanielOmine então, eu fiz isso. Como disse, só tenho um repositório, pelo menos só aparece um na listagem.

Comment: @DanielOmine se eu fizer php5 -v eu consigo obter 5.16 (cli) mas se fizer php -v obtenho o 5.3.

Comment: @DanielOmine eu li e reli esse tópico, mas veja, o autor diz que ao executar o comando `apt-get install php5` é instalado a versão 7 do PHP. Eu entendi o porque, ele tinha um repositório apontando para o PHP7. Ele removeu esse repositório e adicionou o correto para o PHP5. No meu caso eu já fiz isso tudo, só tenho 1 repositório para o PHP5, porém continuo a conseguir executar o comando `php -v` e `php5 -v`.

Comment: @DanielOmine parece que o comportamento é padrão, pelo menos no Ubuntu. Vi uma instalação que funciona corretamente e existe as 2 opções, `php -v` e `php5 -v`, porém possuem a mesma versão do PHP. Pelo que entendi podemos ter 2 versões do PHP, uma anterior a 5 e outra superior/igual a 5, por isso é mantido o PHP e PHP5.

Comment: @DanielOmine de qualquer forma consegui resolver o problema: removi todos os repositórios existentes, removi todos os pacotes existentes, removi a pasta do binário do PHP, e voltei a reinstalar tudo novamente. Funcionou, porém ainda não tenho a reposta para a pergunta, o que eu fiz para ter 2 versões diferentes do PHP?